# Does the ARM A9 support OpenCL acceleration?

Tags: opencv, arm, opencl

I'm trying to figure out if http://www.solid-run.com/products/hummingboard/ will be able to run OpenCV with OpenCL accelerations. Attempting to do this on the Raspberry Pi was fruitless.

Comment: What's the relevance of A9? Isn't the point of OpenCL to run it on the GPU, not the CPU?

Comment: I understood the A9 to have an integrated GPU, hence the question. Please let me know if that's wrong.

Comment: Nope, Cortex-A9 is just a CPU core, which licensees then integrate with other stuff to make an actual chip. There are A9-based SoCs with all manner of GPUs (including none at all) - What you care about in the case of the Hummingboard is whether whatever GPU the Freescale i.MX6 SoC has supports OpenCL. A quick serach for "i.MX6 OpenCL" suggests it does.

Comment: Oh awesome- that's exactly what I came for! Thanks! If you paste it as an answer below I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1):

The Ocl library for OpenCl acceleration for OpenCV requires OpenCL with FULL PROFILE.                                                                     Vivate GPU in Freescale iMX6q only supports Embedded Profile(EP). 
You cannot use OpenCL acceleration in OpenCV in this case.